# Laravel - Append to auth user for only current session

Tags: php, laravel, session

I want to append a value to the auth user

```
auth()->user() OR Auth::user()
```

For only their currently logged in session. (ie. they logout or the auth session expires and the value is lost).

```
Auth::user()->isTheOne = true;
```

The above code will only work for the current request and will not persist across further requests. How can I achieve this. So that when I try and access the above code from a different request with the same user it won't show null?

Comment: The common way would be to extend the User Class and tell authorization to use that class. This can be set in the config/auth.php file under 'providers->users->model'

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to persist data during a session you'll want to look into using the sessions facade Laravel provides. A simple example would be

```
// Via a request instance...
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');

// Via the global helper...
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

For more information regarding sessions and Laravel [read the documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session).

Comment: Is this for the authenticated users session though or the whole apps session?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `isTheOne` function in your user's class:

```
public function isTheOne() {
    session(['is_the_one' => true]);
}
```

Then call your method in a Controller or somewhere else:

```
Auth::user()->isTheOne();
```

**EDIT**

According to your comment, if you want something more generic, you could try:

```
public function __set($key, $value) {
    session([$key => true]);
    parent::__set($key, $value);
}
```

So everytime you call `Auth::user()->isTheOne = true;` or something like that, it will be recorder into session. It seems weird to me, but if it's what you want, ok (maybe I misunderstood something).

Comment: I want it to be dynamic as I don't actually have pre defined fields so this solution doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just set the session then,

```
public function postUpdate(Request $request) {

    if ($request->session()->has('user') {
        $user = $request->session()->get('user');

    } else {

        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->isTheOne = true;
        $request->session()->put('user', $user);

   }


}
```